# Insert the input into mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, arr

I am a newbie in programming. Excuse my ignorance.
My english is not too good. Hope you understand what I mean in my question.

How can I get the value of id `NILAI` below and insert into mysql.

```
     html += '<tr>';
              html += '<td class="indi" align="center">';
              html += row.nis;
              html += '</td>';
              html += '<td class="indi">';
              html += row.nama_siswa;
              html += '</td>';
              html += '<td>';
              html += '<input id="nilai" type="text" placeholder="nilai"/>';
              html += '</td>';
              html += '</tr>';
```

I want the input value insert into mysql where col `nis` in mysql table same with row. nis

I've been trying this, but It's wrong. It just read the value of the first row in input nilai and make a new nis=0.

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("nilai") ;
var i;
    for (i=0;i<data1.length;i++) {
       var sql='INSERT INTO nilaitugas(no_tugas, nilai) VALUES ("'+dataid+'","'data1.elements[i]. value+'")';
   }
```

Note: dataid is a variabel from url that I need to input.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send the input value to the server.

Comment: You are open to sql injection the way you are writing your query.

Comment: Can you print what is the final value of sql?

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code in javascript to get the value

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("nilai").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
var data1 = document.getElementById("nilai").value; //to get the value in the input tag
var sql='INSERT INTO nilaitugas(no_tugas, nilai) VALUES ("'+dataid+'","'data1+'")';
```

Comment: I use this before, but It's just insert the first value of nilai. I want to insert more than one row in input value, as much as row. nis in the table.

Comment: how many times is "nilai" in your HTML code, as I can see only once. It's confusing.
Also, document.getElementById returns a single element and not an array. If, there are more elements with id="nilai" it will only return the first element. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById